# Storing cookie in string array variable and displaying the string

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, cookies

I am trying to store the cookie in an array of string and splitting it .when i try to display the array i am getting index out of bound error in the for loop.

Please not the the value of "`cboColumn.getSelectedValues()`" is a list of selected columns from a grid which is in format"`column1,column2,column3......columnn`"

```
Response.Cookies["Column"].Value = cboColumn.getSelectedValues();
    String items = Request.Cookies["Column"].Value;
    String[] item = items.Split(',');
    Response.Write(items);
    Response.Write(item[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i <= item.Length; i++)
    {
        Response.Write(item[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `for` loop like this:-

```
for (int i = 0; i <= item.Length - 1; i++)
{
   Response.Write(item[i]);
}
```

Or as suggested by @BillK, you can simply change the condition like this:-

```
for (int i = 0; i < item.Length ; i++)
```

`Array` is zero index based so it will range from `0 to (n-1)` but you are trying to fetch value from 0 to n, which is causing this issue.

Comment: Or, just change <= to =

Comment: @BillK - Yup thnx! Updated.

Comment: @Rahul Singh hi the answer worked .now i am trying to access the cookie in another function but getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.
public void xyz()
{
        String[] items = null;
        String itemss = Request.Cookies["Column"].Value;
        if(!itemss.Equals(""))
            items=itemss.Split(',');
}

protected void cboColumn_OkButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Response.Cookies["Column"].Value = cboColumn.getSelectedValues();
        xyz();
}

Comment: @SumeetHiremath - Debug your code and definitely you'll be able to recognize the bug. Check this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it to know the cause for this issue. Please try to fix and if you are really stuck hard only then post new question.